# Nodejs: Wait for API response during the execution of query

Tags: node.js, express

I am taking an email from the user and checking it in the database(DB2). After that I am sending an HTTP get request to further verify that email from a remote server. After that I am executing the query to verify the user password. However, I am facing a race condition here. My query for password verification begins executing without waiting for the API response from the remote server. How can I resolve that?

Here's my code:

```
conn.query(searchDB, [email], (err, results) => {
      if(!err)
      {
        if(results.length == 0)
        {
          res.send("UnAuthorized");
        }
        else
        {
          // I get the response from the below request
          samaccount = results[0].samaccount;

          http.get(`API-endpoint/${samaccount}`, (res) => {

            let data = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
              data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
              newdata = JSON.parse(data);
              if(newdata.accountStatus == true)
              {
                samaccountvalid = true;
                console.log("User Authorized as per sam account");
              }
              else
              {
                samaccountvalid = false;
                console.log("User NOT Authorized as per sam account");
                return;
              }
            });
          }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
          });
          
          //at the same time this starts executing I want to wait for the above request to complete
          if(samaccountvalid == true)
          {
            console.log("Password is being compared");
            .....comparing password here.....
          }
          ........
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request to the remote API server is a stream. A stream will receive data on chunks and trigger the event `end` when it's complete. Similar to a promise or a callback, the async code will execute and get a response at a later time which means that the password check will execute before the `end` event is ever triggered.
You have 2 ways of handling this:

1. move all your code inside the `end` event
2. If the `http.get` function can return a promise with the entire payload, consider changing the `conn.query` callback function to an async function which enables you to await the response from the `http.get` function first and use the response in your password checker method